# Keyboard is not visible in the second time when reaching

Tags: react-native, keyboard, autofocus

Though the keyboard popup for the first time, when I navigate to the same interface text input field is focused but the keyboard is not popup in React Native Application.

I used `autoFocus={ true }` but I can't see the keyboard. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'push' instead of 'navigate'. When navigating to the same interface componentWillMount/componentDidMount is not loading again. That may be the issue. Try with this.

Refer react navigation documentation.
[React Navigation Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **ScrollView**, add **keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"**

```
  <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
   ------
  </ScrollView>
```